# Add a language to the display / client language choices

Tags: sitecore-client

I want to add a language to the display languages so that the `admin` interface can be translated.

I have added a language, I have uploaded and imported the language, but it is not showing in the `Display language` drop down.

I can export all the translations from the top node in the `Content Editor`, and I see the language I added, but not some of the languages in the `Display language` list.

How do I get my new language added to that list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add another `Client Language` to be displayed e.g. in `User Manager` you need to go to Sitecore Dekstop, switch to `core` database and add new language with correct `iso` code under `/sitecore/system/Languages` node:

[image]

Comment: I marked this as the answer because you pointed me to the desktop, and then switch to the `core` db. I still had to go to the `control panel`, add a language and then import the language file.